# How can i find the title of the image from the table using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I need help how I can get the teams column from the table from this https://www.hltv.org/stats

This code gives me all values from the table but I did not get the value of teams because it is in in form of images(Hyperlink). I want to get the title of the teams.

```
r = requests.get("https://www.hltv.org/stats/players")

# Create a pandas with pulled data
root = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
root.prettify()

# Pull the player data out of the table and put into our dataframe
table = (str)(root.find("table"))
players = pd.read_html(table, header=0)[0]
```

I need to get all teams as a pandas column with a header as a team

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the team name is contained in the `alt` attribute of the team images, you can simply replace the `<td>` content with the values from the `alt` attributes:

```
table = root.find("table")

for td in table('td', class_='teamCol'):
    teams = [img['alt'] for img in td('img')]
    td.string = ', '.join(teams)

players = pd.read_html(str(table), header=0)[0]
```

Gives

```
       Player                                 Teams  Maps  K-D Diff   K/D  Rating1.0
 0       ZywOo                         Vitality, aAa   612      3853  1.39       1.29
 1      s1mple  Natus Vincere, FlipSid3, HellRaisers  1153      6153  1.31       1.24
 2       sh1ro                     Gambit Youngsters   317      1848  1.39       1.21
 3        Kaze               ViCi, Flash, MVP.karnal   613      3026  1.31       1.20
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `requests`, `pandas` and `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

req = requests.get("https://www.hltv.org/stats/players")
root = bs(req.text, "html.parser")
# Find the first table in the page
table = root.find('table', {'class': 'stats-table player-ratings-table'})
# Find all td with class "teamCol"
teams = table.find_all('td', {'class': 'teamCol'})
# Get img source & title from all img tags in teams 
imgs = [(elm.get('src'), elm.get('title')) for team in teams for elm in team.find_all('img')]
# Create your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(imgs, columns=['source', 'title'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                             source            title
0     https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/9565         Vitality
1     https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/5639              aAa
2     https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/4608    Natus Vincere
3     https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/5988         FlipSid3
4     https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/5310      HellRaisers
...                                             ...              ...
1753  https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/4602          Tricked
1754  https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/4501  ALTERNATE aTTaX
1755  https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/7217           subtLe
1756  https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/5454             SKDC
1757  https://static.hltv.org/images/team/logo/6301           Splyce

[1758 rows x 2 columns]
```